# Simple linear interpolation on client side for multiplayer game(Nodejs + JS)

Tags: node.js

I am trying to interpolate a fast-moving object for my multiplayer game. To interpolate I use the following formula:

```
ActiveTime = SpawnTime - Now;
UpdateFrames = ActiveTime / UpdateTime
X = UpdateFrames * SpeedX + StartX
Y = UpdateFrames * SpeedY + StartY
```

Where ActiveTime is the time the object has been in existence, UpdateTime is how many milliseconds the position of the bullet should be updated(add speedx to x and speedy to y), UpdateFrames is the number of frames that have passed since the object was created, and speed and start x and y are the speed and spawn position of the object.

This is only coded client side, so players can see entities rendered at the actual framerate at they can run the game at in case the server tick rate is low from lag or something. My problem is I can't figure out how to get the spawn time of the bullet client side since the there is a latency between the server and client the bullet will be slightly delayed. If I set a variable to the object with the Date.getTime() of the object creation and use that on the client side for some reason there is a inconsistency with UTC time from my server to my client. I had a similar problem when I was trying to code ping.

How do I get an exact date that works for both nodejs and normal js UTC time that refers to the exact same moment in time?

Comment: Inconsistency as in separated by a few seconds?

Comment: I have the same issue! I’m also confused on how to deal with this inconsistency. What I did is having a constant ping-pong and measure latency and approximate the creation time. But it’s not ideal. Still looking..